# Rails: whats the best way to divide a large group of users to run a task in different days without repeating the same user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm coding an automated mailer report for my Rails app and I want to divide thousands of users into 7 different groups to send e-mails to one group each weekday (`Time.now.wday`).

The reason is if the mailer is fired at the same time for everybody, a traffic spike will occur and support might not handle all those users at the same time.

What's the best way of dividing users so that:

- The rake task is run once a week, and the user should only be in one group in the same week (so he doesn't get mailed twice in the same week)
- The # of users can grow during the week (new users) and they need to be included in one group at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most common approaches is to keep track of the date and time when you last sent an email to an user.

You add a `last_emailed_at` column to your users table.

Then you can have the `rake` task query the first X number of users

```
where('last_emailed_at IS NULL OR last_emailed_at < ?', 1.week.ago)
```

You should order the results by `last_emailed_at` in `ascending` order (with `NULLS FIRST` if your database supports it).

Comment: Mihai, that is exactly the solution I was considering. But when I add this column, it's blank. So the query `.where("last_emailed_at < 1.week.ago")` returns nothing. What do you suggest >

Comment: Check against blank as well, `where('last_emailed_at IS NULL OR last_emailed_at < ?', 1.week.ago)`